# MongoDB Network Access section and IP Addresses List

Tags: mongodb, ip-address

## Question Summary

Are IPs machine dependent? Or dependent on the "source" of internet connection?

## Question Details

I am using MongoDB. MongoDB has a section called "Network Access". This section consists of a list of IP Addresses from which I can connect to my cluster.

I added the IP Address of when I was connected to my home wifi from my laptop to the "Network Access" section. Later, I went outside and connected from my phone (using personal hotspot). I realized that the IP Address was now different. And so I had to include the new IP Address to the "Network Access" section.

**Why is this?**

Comment: IP addresses are not necessarily static or unique. Not the best source, but a good starting point to learn more about IPs: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address

Answer (score 0):

Your public IP address is given to you by a so called DHCP Server that is responsible for the network your device is connected to. When you are at home, that IP address is is given to you by the ISP that is responsible for connecting your home router to the internet. When you are connecting from your phone, that phone is receiving an adress assigned by the ISP from you mobile plan.
Dependent on your ISP, your home IP will likely also change in the future.
To summarize, you should find other ways to limit connectivity to your MongoDB instance such as tunneling, VPN, or proxy authentication. IP filtering is flawed as the only access prevention system.